# Download and display array of UIImages SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am a beginner in SwiftUI and am trying to load and display multiple images horizontally at once. When I debug, it looks like the platformLogos exists and the ForEach loop is running, but nothing appears on the screen. The .border(.blue) is not appearing either.

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    
    private static let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
    
    @Published var image: UIImage? = nil
    @Published var images: [UIImage]? = nil
    
    public func downloadImage(url: URL) {
        let urlString = url.absoluteString
        
        if let imageFromCache = ImageLoader.imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = imageFromCache
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, error) in
            guard let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                ImageLoader.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString  as AnyObject)
                self?.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    public func downloadImages(urls: [URL]) {
        for url in urls {
            let urlString = url.absoluteString
            
            if let imageFromCache = ImageLoader.imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
                self.images?.append(imageFromCache)
                return
            }
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, error) in
                guard let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    ImageLoader.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString  as AnyObject)
                    self?.images?.append(image)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

```
@ObservedObject var logoLoader: ImageLoader = ImageLoader()
@ObservedObject var gameDetail: GameDetail = GameDetail()

var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
        platformLogoView(platformLogos: self.logoLoader.images)
        .onAppear {
            if let logoURLs = self.gameDetail.game?.platformLogosUrls {
                self.logoLoader.downloadImages(urls: logoURLs)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct platformLogoView: View {
    var platformLogos: [UIImage]?
    let rows = [GridItem(.fixed(30)), GridItem(.fixed(30))]
    
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            ForEach(platformLogos ?? [UIImage](), id: \.self ) { logo in
                GridRow {
                    Image(uiImage: logo)
                        .resizable(resizingMode: Image.ResizingMode.stretch)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .clipped()
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .border(.blue)
    }
}
```

I created the downloadImages function and simply followed the same logic as the singular downloadImage function, but appending the loaded image to an array. I was thinking of using lazyHGrid instead of Grid but neither of them worked. I am simply not seeing anything on screen.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ObservedObject` -- you should be using `StateObject`

Comment: @jnpdx Which one should be StateObject? I tried logoLoader then gameDetail then both but none of them worked

Comment: Both should be. It may not be your only issue, but it is one problem, for sure.

Comment: Check your horizontally UI first & Do not load images. Use Rectangle View in place of Image View.   if your horizontal UI is okay then you can check with images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you should identify the “source of truth”, and if passing it around, use `@Binding`. E.g.:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var logoLoader: ImageLoader = ImageLoader()       // NB: @StateObject
    @StateObject var gameDetail: GameDetail = GameDetail()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            PlatformLogoView(platformLogos: $logoLoader.images)    // NB: Binding with $
        }
        .task { 
            if let logoURLs = gameDetail.game?.platformLogosUrls {
                logoLoader.downloadImages(urls: logoURLs)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And

```swift
struct PlatformLogoView: View {
    @Binding var platformLogos: [UIImage]                         // NB: @Binding
    let rows = [GridItem(.fixed(30)), GridItem(.fixed(30))]
    
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            ForEach(platformLogos, id: \.self) { logo in
                GridRow {
                    Image(uiImage: logo)
                        .resizable(resizingMode: .stretch)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .clipped()
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .border(.blue)
    }
}
```

And to simplify the code, I made `images` not be an optional. (I also added logging of error statement so I could make sure the problem wasn’t in this network code; silently failing/returning on error makes debugging exceptionally hard.)

```swift
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {    
    private static let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
    
    @Published var images: [UIImage] = []                        // NB: Not optional
    
    public func downloadImages(urls: [URL]) {
        for url in urls {
            let urlString = url.absoluteString
            
            if let imageFromCache = ImageLoader.imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
                images.append(imageFromCache)
                return
            }
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, error) in
                guard let data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    print(#function, "failed \(error ?? ImageLoaderError.notImage)")
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    print(#function, urlString)
                    ImageLoader.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                    self?.images.append(image)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}

enum ImageLoaderError: Error {
    case notImage
}
```

For more information on the flow of data within a SwiftUI app, see WWDC 2019 video [Data Flow Through SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/).

Comment: There are a ton of additional recommendations I would make in this code, but I restricted myself (largely) to the issue at hand. But if you are open to additional recommendations, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the debug statements made me realize it was an issue with my backend code that I am wrestling with now. I am definitely open to additional recommendations! @Rob

Comment: First, a tactical observation on the cache: This is a generic, so I’d use a `URL` for the key, and a `UIImage` for the value. E.g., `let imageCache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()`. Then to add an image from the cache: `Self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url as NSURL)`. And to get an image from the cache: `Self.imageCache.object(forKey: url as NSURL)`. This just eliminates the need to cast objects retrieved from the cache as `UIImage`, and makes the key a little more obvious.

Comment: Second, this technique will not return images in the order of the `URL`s, but rather will return them in the order that the concurrent requests finish. You’d probably want to keep track of which image is associated with which URL, and then return the images in the same order that `gameDetail.game` returned them.

Comment: Third, I might suggest cutting the Gordian knot and using [`AsyncImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage/) and retire this image loader stuff entirely. That not only ensures that the order is preserved, it lets you easily show `ProgressView` for images still being retrieved (as shown in that documentation), etc. To handle point two, in my previous comment, gets a little hairy, so ask yourself if you really need/want to do all that.

Comment: Fourth, you talked about wanting to return a horizontal grid of images, but it looks like you are creating a vertical presentation of images (each image with its own `GridRow`). I’m sure the presentation in the UI will jump out at you once you fix your backend (and use the `@Binding`, as discussed in my answer), but FYI.

Comment: Fifth, nowadays we would generally use Swift concurrency (e.g.,  `URLSession.shared.data(from:)` instead of `dataTask(with:)`, isolate observable object to `@MainActor`, lose the GCD calls, etc.

Comment: But the idea is that you want it to load them concurrently, but show them in order, with ProgressView for downloads still in progress, and some error indicator if any failed. E.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvUZz.gif (I deliberately gave the first two invalid URLs).